# Reading in a "space" using a system call [with C, in Unix]

Tags: c, unix, system-calls

I basically want my program to ask me `"Press space to continue or Ctrl-C to exit"`

There's a twist though, I cannot use anything other than system calls. How would I go about using the `read` call (or something similar to do this). I've done a similar example of this writing a script for Bash but I cannot get it working in C.

Comment: Use libc functions, namely `getch()`.

Answer (score 0):

by default read blocks waiting for a buffer of data.  It can be made non-blocking, but easiest is to read one byte at a time.  You pass it the address of the buffer to read into and the capacity of the buffer, ie `char buf[1]; read(0, buf, 1); if (buf[0] == ' ') ...`